# How to load a pdf file from the assets folder in android

Tags: android, pdf, viewer

I'm a new bee in android programming. Do you have any ideas on how to read a PDF file programmatically if the file is from the assets directory?Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried it myself but there are many good tutorials out there. Try this http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/17/using-assets-in-android/

Reading pdf or any file is similar. Try googling more about "reading files from asset folder" if the tutorial above does not help you

Answer (score 0):

you can use iText for reading pdf.

There is a link : http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPDF/article.html
note : in above link they have used path of the file on pc like c:/documents/temp.pdf on the place of same give path of ur SDcard or asset.

Hope this may help u,
Try to search on net u will definitely get some stuff....
All The Best

Comment: Richa, the link you gave did not work...it always cancels the installation everytime i run the android app

Answer (score 0):

This is how you read pdf file from assets folder and save it to your SDCard :

```
AssetManager is = this.getAssets();
InputStream fis = is.open("excerpt.pdf");

FileOutputStream fos  = new FileOutputStream(
                   new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "excerpt_DEC.pdf"));



        byte[] b = new byte[8];
        int i;

        while ((i = fis.read(b)) != -1) {
                      fos.write(b, 0, i);
                    }
        fos.flush(); fos.close();
       fis.close();
```

You can change the save destination if you want.

Comment: Thank you for you answers...but the code given does not take effect. I also want to display the pdf from my assets folder to the screen. How can it be done?