# PDF File not opening on Nougat+

Tags: android, pdf

I'm creating an app, and in this app have a button to open an PDF with a calendar with activities of user...

The PDF is in assets folder.

And the actualy code is:

```
    private void abrirCalendario() {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        File fileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/");
        fileDir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(fileDir, "Calendario DAERG.pdf");
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Calendario DAERG.pdf";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".provider", new File(path));

            List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
                String packageName = "tk.davidev.android.ews";
                grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            }
        }else {
            uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
        }

        if(!file.exists()) {
            try {
                InputStream in = assetManager.open("calendario_2017.pdf");
                OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                copyFile(in, out);
                in.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

And the error i'm getting is:
`file:///storage/emulated/0/Calendario DAERG.pdf exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()`

Answer (score 0):

Hi because Android from Mashmellow , I think, changes its segurity behavior such as request for permission on runtime or using FileProvider to manage URI. Now me have to give permission in some code in order to work.
Here's an example of open Intent with ACTION_VIEW in Nougat

```
File archivo= new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"excerpt_DEC.pdf");    
Uri  uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    archivo);  
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri,"application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(intent);
```

My example is the same as yours. I read a file from assets then, I find that file created and save it in *archivo* object. Later on, get an uri with FileProvider method and finally, I give permissions to intent with this line

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

I leave you this link for background knowledge about this new implementation.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html
Also, I followed this anwser to read my file.pdf from asset 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7495078/8650422
Hope to help, greetings !